# why javascript automatically passing the result of an function as a parameter to the next function

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript and i find this often on tuitorials i watch. Javascript automatically pass the result of a function as a parameter to the next function.

```
fetch('SampleApi')
.then( function(data) { return data.json() } )
.then( function(data) { console.log(data.name); } )
.catch(function(err) { console.log(error) })
```

the result of the fetch goes directly as a parameter to the function then the result of the function goes directly as a parameter to the next function.

I just want to know what is this and what is this called. I need to understand this before diving deep.

Comment: That's how a Promise works.

Comment: You'll find array methods like `.map()`, `.filter()`, etc, also demonstrate similar behavior, where you're defining function parameters but you don't actually see where they get passed. At a high level, as Pointy says, that's just "how it works". These callback functions will be invoked with a certain list of arguments as defined in their documentation. For example, the `.map()` callback will be invoked with arguments corresponding to [`currentValue`, `index`, and `array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Parameters).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: I don't think this question relates to Promises specifically. *"i find this often on tuitorials i watch. Javascript automatically pass the result of a function as a parameter to the next function. I just want to know what is this and what is this called"* - It's using Promises as an example to ask about high-level concepts (like method-chaining and callback arguments). (**EDIT:** He confirms this in a comment below: *"this question is not about promises this question is about javascript automatically passing an argument to the functions. Thank you"*)

Comment: thank you, as a beginner i like things being done as i see it. This is the first time i encountered this. Thank you for clearing this up.

Comment: There is nothing automatic about it  it is the way Promises are designed. It might help to look at a purely JavaScript implementation of Promises, E.G. https://github.com/then/promise/blob/master/src/core.js

Comment: You can see on line 123 in that file for example, when a promise resolves with a value, it calls `tryCallOne` and passes in the onFulfilled callback (which is the callback function you passed into `then`) and the value. `tryCallOne` just calls your function and passes the value in as an argument.

Comment: In other words, there is nothing automatic or special about the argument being passed, and for that reason it doesn't really have a name. It is just the way Promises were designed. Promises were originally implemented in JavaScript, like the implementation I linked above, before they became part of the language a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: modified example to show passing parameters between methods to directly answer the qeustion.

The underlying premise is that JavaScript can act upon a returned result immediately as long as the operation requested is sane and available. A simple example is shown here:

```js
console.log("|" + "   This is a string with extra spaces   ".trim() + "|");
```

This can be accomplished in your own code as well. In the following example, note the return of the operation is the object itself. This allows us to carry out any operation available within that object upon the return from some other operation in the same object:

```js
class Test {
  sayHi(message = "Passed Message") {
    console.log('parameter: ' + message);
    this.message = message;
    return this;
  }

  sayBye(cb) {
    cb(this.message);
    return this;
  }
}

const test = new Test();
test.sayHi("hello!").sayBye(passed => console.log('passed in: ' + passed));
```

So throughout your experience with JavaScript you will find many instances of this idea that is called method chaining.

In the example you provided, it is simply this concept applied to the `fetch` API.

Answer (score 0):

It's called function chaining.

The `fetch` function returns an object that has a function `then`, which accepts a function as its parameter.

When `then` is called, it executes the given function with the data stored within the object as a parameter, and stores the return value as the new internal data, which is passed to the function in the second `then` call. `then` returns the same object that was returned from `fetch`.

The call to `catch` will check if an error was encountered (and stored into the object), and if so, will call the given function with the error.

You could spread out the whole thing, without chaining:

```
var o = fetch('SampleApi');
o = o.then(function(data) { return data.json(); });
o = o.then(function(data) { console.log(data.name); });
o.catch(function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

Comment: Chaining usually refers to a method that returns the object it was called on (I.E. `return this;`). I've never heard it be used to describe functions that return newly created objects (Promises in this case) before.

Comment: @Paulpro I don't know the implementation details of Promise, but there is no reason why it couldn't `return this;` internally for `fetch` and `then` -- it certainly behaves like that when you use it. MDN on Promise also talks about chaining for this behavior: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Chaining

Comment: There are many reasons why it couldn't `return this;` and has to construct a new Promise instead, but the main ones are: 1) You can call `then` more than once on a Promise. 2) Promises can't switch states back to pending.

Comment: MDN is a wiki and often has incorrect terminology on it. I'm not saying that it is wrong to call this chaining though; just that I've never heard it used for this and I'm used to it having the meaning I mentioned above.

Comment: This is also just a wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining It is common for builders to return itself for each setter, but e.g. for streams on Java, the returned object changes on each step of the chain.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "That's just how promises work"

To better illustrate WHY this is good behavior:

```
function getOrganizedData() {
    return fetch("somedata").then(function(rawData) {
        // do some stuff
        return organizedData;
    });
}
```

Anyone using this function will be able to use the `organizedData` - so if you have a shared service, only that service needs to know how to translate `rawData` into `organizedData` for the rest of the application to use.

---

What if that's not the behavior you want?

Easy, just don't chain the promises:

```
const fetchPromise = fetch('SampleApi');
fetchPromise.then( function(data) { return data.json() } );
fetchPromise.then( function(data) { console.log(data.name); } );
fetchPromise.catch(function(err) { console.log(error) });
```

But wait, won't I get errors with that approach because the `catch` isn't applied to each chain?

Yes! So, you need to catch BOTH chains:

```
const errorFunction = function(err) { console.log(error) };
const fetchPromise = fetch('SampleApi');
fetchPromise.then( function(data) { return data.json() } ).catch(errorFunction);
fetchPromise.then( function(data) { console.log(data.name); } ).catch(errorFunction);
```

---

NOTE: This chaining behavior applies to `.catch` as well:

```
fetch("somethingThatWillError")
.then(function() { console.log("THEN - I will not run because there's an error"); })
.catch(function() { console.log("CATCH - I will run because I am handling the error"); })
.then(function() { console.log("THEN - I will run because the error has been handled"); })
.catch(function() { console.log("CATCH - I will not run because there is no error to handle"); })
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit : For resume, the result of `fetch` is the first `data` in case of success, the second `data` is the return of the first `then` and `err` the result of `fetch` in case of reject.

You are actually playing with promise here, you can look some documentation about Promise [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

In javascript your running task can be synchronous or asynchronous, promise is for handling asynchronous task. You can know more about asynchronous [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous).

To be quick and simple a promise can be resolve now, in ten minutes or never. When you are building a Promise, you need an executor which is passed with two arguments, a resolve function and a reject function, they will be call just before the final resolution of your promise, (after an API call for exemple).

The reject gonna be call if your promise fail (timed out on your api call for example) and the resolve gonna be call on the success of your promise. In this two callbacks (resolve and promise), if you don't know about callback you have to learn it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), you will have an argument with the return of the resolution of your promise, for example if the promise is rejected you gonna have the reason in a message and in the resolve you gonna have the data that you need from your api call.

In your case, the `fetch` is build like `fetch = new Promise(...);` where `then(...)` is the success resolver and `catch(...)` the rejected resolver. You can have a `finally(...)` which is called after the `then()` and `catch()`.
And the `data` in your example is the result of your promise if it's a success and `err` is the result in case of error result.

Comment: This explains promises well but I believe it misses the point of OP's question to an extent, which seems to be *"What is <this thing where the arguments are automatically passed to the next method> called, that I keep seeing all over the place in JavaScript?"*